# Tool that combines JSON Schema driven form generation with CMS on GIT tool?

Tags: git, json, configuration-management

I am looking for a configuration GUI that is constrained by something like jsonschema and versioned with git.

I am looking for a tool that combines the functions of something like: https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/ with something like: https://alternativeto.net/software/forestry/

I would want the ability to use the user info and their group info to determine which branch/repo to use for reading and committing.

Does such a thing exist yet?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for **FrontAid CMS**. It is a [CMS for JSON files in Git](https://frontaid.io/). You can define a data model using JSON and the model itself is contstrained by JSON Schema. Based on the model, FrontAid then generates the forms that can be filled with content. The content is then stored in a JSON file in your own Git repository. Is that what you were looking for?

Disclaimer: I work at FrontAid. Also I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "ability to use the user info and their group info [...]". Please feel free to get in touch. You can find our email address here: https://frontaid.io/docs/